# Python: How to import a class from a parent directory

Tags: python, import

I am running a python-script that imports a class that I have created. This is the directory order:

```
Classes
  - myClass.py
Scripts
  - myScript.py
```

The first line of myScript.py reads:

```
from Classes.myClass import myClass
```

I have also tried:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from Classes.myClass import myClass
```

And I have tried to include an empty `__init__.py` file to the Classes folder.

With any of these ways, I end up with the error message:

"  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Classes'  "

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you have to add another __init__.py file with the same level of the directories.

Comment: did you try `from ..Classes.myClass import myClass`? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63412379/python-how-to-import-a-class-from-a-parent-directory)

Answer (score 0):

From your top level directory
(I'm assuming it's the one containing Classes/ and Scripts/)
run: `python3 -m Scripts.myScript`

From `man python3`:

```
-m module-name
              Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the
              corresponding .py file as a script.
```